# What does FSFS stand for as related to subversion?

Tags: svn, repository, visualsvn-server, fsfs

I have scoured the internet looking for a clear answer and cannot find one. What does it stand for? I am currently trying to set up a new repo for our development team and I would like to know what this term means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FSFS stands for a "[filesystem atop of the filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#FSFS)" or in the original Subversion 1.1. release notes when FSFS was released, "[...a Filesystem implementation that uses the OS filesystem to store data](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.1.html)".

Answer (score 2):

I think it's File system file system - which seems silly. 
the [red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends.fsfs) don't actually define it

Comment: It doesn't sound silly to me, as it implements a versioned file system on top of a "normal" file system, as opposed to storing it in a Berkeley DB as before.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning, Why Berkeley? Shouldn't MySQLite be the candidate in mind?

Comment: Please read the question, it's about Subversion and they have chosen Berkely in the past.

Comment: @Pacerier Assuming `MySQLite` is a typo and you meant `SQLite`, it was not an option when SVN was first created. Both projects started in 2000.